# How can I get React to Replace (not Merge) VDOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component which, in `componentDidMount`, gives a jQuery plugin some control over the DOM rendered by React. I know everyone says "never let anything but React touch the DOM", but hear me out, as reinventing this plugin is not feasible right now, and I think there should be an "overwrite whatever you find in the DOM" switch for React that I hope someone can point me to.

More info: I've designed it so the state of the React's DOM is *entirely* determined from the props given to React *except* while the user is dragging things around. Once dropped, I don't care how the DOM changed since the last React update, I just want to render everything from the current `props` of React, which I am passing in on the plugin's `change` handler via `ReactDOM.render`

The symptoms are that the nodes created by the plugin during and after dragging don't go away after React is told to update!

Yes, the nodes are `key`-ed initially.

The plugin is Nestable, and it adds interactivity (drag-drop reordering of the tree), and a JSBin is here: http://jsbin.com/qareki/edit?js,console,output

I'm really looking for the "Kill whatever you find" setting. I thought calling `ReactDOM.render` would do it, but it's clearly not doing it. Neither of course, was the more surgical `setState`, but I didn't expect it to. Thanks in advance for all 'you're doing-it-wrong' advice and other fixe

Comment: Is it possible you're going about it the wrong way? I'm not trying to be a dick, I'm actually just wondering why you're even using React if your app depends so heavily on this jQuery plugin. I'm sure you have reasons, but I think I'd really go back to the drawing board here. I know that doesn't help you immediately.

Comment: Todd, thanks. My goal is to create a clean React wrapper over this JQuery plugin so it can be composed with the rest of the system. But perhaps a full migration is in order ?

Comment: Perhaps, if the goal was to see what the performance benefits were of React, this project won't really show that because the state of your app is being managed by the jQuery plugin. React is really just rendering (probably somewhat slowly) the outcome of that, and it's not using it's internal diff algorithm. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/advanced-performance.html

Comment: I see, so you want to be able to include this jQuery plugin as a component within a wider React system? I think probably no easy way out, a full migration is probably the only way but perhaps try the answer below as an interim.

Answer (score 1):

Manually add a `div` element in `componentDidMount` and replace it with a new one in `componentDidUpdate`:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
    render() {
      // whatever HTML you want...
      return (
        <div>
          <div>
            {/* this div will contain our non-React stuff that we need to reset */}
            <div ref="container"></div>
          </div>
        </div>);
    }

    blastAndRecreate() {
      // throw away any content within the container and replace it with brand new content
      const container = $(this.refs.container).empty();
      const newDIV = $("<div>").appendTo(container);

      // give this new DIV to nestable plugin
      newDIV.nestable(...);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.blastAndRecreate();
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
      this.blastAndRecreate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't `unmountComponentAtNode` a bit more idiomatic React ? I mean - since we're in JQuery land already, a little more won't hurt, but I've had errors along the lines of `Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: processUpdates(): Unable to find child 0 of element. This probably means the DOM was unexpectedly mutated (e.g., by the browser)` trying to further mutate the DOM - what's your take on it ?

Comment: You should edit your post to include some relevant code

Comment: Thanks @Brandon - I ended up using component unmounting instead, when `empty()` ran into troubles. Here's a full write-up of how I got through it: http://blog.testdouble.com/posts/2016-02-01-react-reconciliation.html